# Async function not returning value after getting firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I set up a project to return a value to app.js without it having to process the promise. This code returns undefined when I run it. Any Tips?

**export.js**
`

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const db = admin.firestore();
const ref = db.collection('Things')

async function getNameV(ting) {
  return await ref.get().then(doc => {
   doc.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
    var data = documentSnapshot.data()
    if (ting == data.name || ting == data.id) {
     return data.name
    }
   })
 })
};

module.exports.getName = function(ting) {
  getNameV(ting).then(value =>{
    console.log(value)
    return value;
  })
};
```

**app.js**

```
 const exp = require('./export.js')
 var name = await exp.getName('foo')
 console.log(name)
```

Comment: Meaningless, why you use `.then` when you have `async/await`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to **return** the promise created in your `module.exports.getName` function, like this:

```
module.exports.getName = function(ting) {
    return getNameV(ting).then(value =>{
        console.log(value)
        return value;
    });
};
```

Then, on the `app.js` side, you have to make sure you call the exported function from an `async` function (otherwise you wouldn't be able to call it using `await`):

```
const exp = require('./export.js')
async function start() {
    var name = await exp.getName('foo')
    console.log(name);
}
start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hugo is correct, but you have another error in addition to that.  `getNameV` isn't even returning a promise that yields the value your looking for.  `return data.name` is actually just returning from the anonymous function passed to forEach().  That value doesn't make it into the promise that you return from `getNameV`.  Right now, it is literally just returning a promise that contains undefined right now.

Also, `return await [promise]` is redundant here.  You can just `return [promise]`, and not even both marking `getNameV` with `async`.